# Recover Hibernated partition

Tags: linux, hibernate, data-recovery

I accidently formatted my ntfs windows partition with "mkfs.ext4".
I was able to recover it with testdisk but it seems that the windows partition was hibernated,
so whenever i tried to open windows it starts repairing disk errors which was taking too long,
so i manually chkdsk ,to which after some time it started telling -"unreadable sector........
which also took very long so i shut it down.
In kali linux whenever i tried to mount it with "mount /dev/sda3 /mnt -t ntfs -r"
it mounts but many of the folders are empty including windows,program files,Users.
I am new to linux,can you tell me steps to recover my files if possible windows...
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY` where XY is the partition name. ex:`sda4`. use gparted to find partition name. Then mount. It may help.

Comment: all it does that it tries to unlock the drive (done by windows during hibernation). If successful, then after mounting you'll be able to see more files in empty folders. (If you don't see, that means they are lost, you need recovery tools similar to Recuva). If unsuccessful then no harm is done.

Comment: Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

First check to see it the partition is mounted, it maybe mounted as Read-only. Then issue the mount command with the options.
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/yourWindowsPartition /media/yourUser/WindowsPartitionName